# Is there any statistical cost to adding further levels to a time series hierarchy from a forecast perspective?

Tags: r, forecasting, multilevel-analysis

For example, when using gts() and forecast.gts() in r, should I prefer a model of product category -> product OR product category -> product -> subproduct?

What does it depend on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be answered in the abstract. It all depends very much on your specific situation and time series.

You will of course want to include all hierarchy levels you actually need forecasts for. The question is whether including any additional levels might improve the forecasts for the *relevant* levels.

This could certainly happen. For instance, you may be interested in the overall total forecast (for cash flow planning) as well as in stock keeping unit (SKU) level forecasts (for reordering). Certain effects might be visible on intermediate levels. For instance, certain categories may exhibit seasonality. Or you may run promotions on certain groups of SKUs. In such cases, the signal may be too weak to see on SKU level, but too noisy on total aggregate level, and you may be able to estimate it better on some intermediate level.

If, on the other hand, your intermediate levels do not align with any specific dynamics of your time series, it might in fact happen that adding these intermediate levels only adds noise and makes overall forecasts worse. As I wrote above, it's hard to discuss this in the abstract.

The main cost will usually come in the form of numerical issues with large hierarchies. The reconciliation quickly turns into a pretty big GLS system.